# React native use effect es-lint error with react query

Tags: react-native, eslint, react-query

I am getting mutate() function from react-query hook and passing it into the use effect, but use effect is showing error that it has a missing dependency mutate. Either include it or remove the dependency array.

Below is the code sample.

```
const {track, setTrack} = useState(null)
const {mutate} = useTracker()

useEffect(() => {
if(track?.tracking) {
mutate()
}
}, [track]) // This line is throwing the es-lint error
```

what am I missing here, because I don't think I can pass mutate function in array dependency.

Comment: what is `variation ` ?

Comment: @DipanSharma Updated the code, it was track not variation.

Comment: also please paste the error for better idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can and should pass `mutate` as dependency to useEffect. The function is guaranteed to be stable across re-renders, so it won’t do any harm, but the linter can’t know that.